# Latest Update brings Github error on pull, push, or sync

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, we have been using the GitHub extension successfully since before release.  Now, all of the sudden, when we push, pull, or sync, we receive the following in the Output window:

```
Warning: 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' has a dubious owner: '(unknown)'.
For security reasons, it is therefore ignored.
To fix this, please transfer ownership to an admininstrator.
```

Comment: What user/group owns `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`? (Here it is the (local) Administrators group.)

Comment: Here as well, the owner is the local Administrators group, on the location and the 'config' file.

Comment: The message claims the owner is `(unknown)` - does it have a direct owner? or is it just that the unknown ownwer is part of the admin group? (stupid questions, I know..)

Comment: **Note** the latest version of Git for Windows (2.24.0) has changed the location of the global configuration, it is now just `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig` (and no longer split between two locations).

Comment: After a fresh install of windows and VS Community 2019, there will be no such file (indeed not even C:\ProgramData). Why is VS's built-in Git expecting it to be there? After installing latest Git for windows (2.24.0), as @Richard pointed out, the correct path to that file is C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig. I do not think manually creating the path and file is the correct solution…

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should check if 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' actually exists. If it doesn't you can just create it and paste the following into the file:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

This worked for me.

Comment: We had 2 separate development machines.  On machine 1, the file existed, but the contents were different from above.  On machine 2, the file did not exist at all.  We made sure the file was present and the contents were as above on both machines, and now no warnings.  Problem solved, but no reason why it happened.  Thanks!

Comment: What Will be the extension of config file?

Comment: @MaulikModi There is no extension specified, windows will simply list its type as 'File'.

Comment: Yes, revisited this post because we had to do it again on a new development computer.  @ChrisDueck is correct. No extension.  Simply name it 'config'

Comment: This answer worked for me after upgrading Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.9.17. I'm wondering if this happened when I uninstalled the previous version (due to upgrade failing).

Answer (score 7):

- Select "Tools" in Visual studio
- Select "Get_tools_and_features"-->It will open the visual studio installer
- Click on the "Individual_components" tab in visual studio installer
- Go to "Code_tools" and check "GitforWindows" and "GitextensionforVisualStudio"
- Install these two to resolve this issue.

**99% sure that above steps will fix the error.**

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by going to Visual Studio Installer, choosing individual component and searching for "Git".
In my case the "Git for Windows" and "GitHub Extension for Visual Studio" was now unchecked/not installed for some reason..

These are the extensions I needed:
[Visual Studio Installer Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2duAt.png)

Installing those create the ProgramData\Git\config file and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

We ran into this exact issue after upgrading Git to version 2.23.0.windows.1 on our build agents.

The fix that worked for us was to change the owner of *C:\ProgramData/Git/config* to *Administrators*. Note that this is different to the *Administrator* user!

To do this, right-click on *C:\ProgramData/Git/config* and select *Properties* then the *Security* tab.

[image: config Properties]

And click *Advanced*...

[image: Advanced Security Settings for config]

Use the *Change* link to set the owner to *Administrators*.

Answer (score 1):

Delete or rename the existing file at that location is also an option. It looks like it's parts of some lower level windows (or MSYS2/Cygwin) security that's brought in via libgit.lib.

Why the created file has the wrong owner is not yet known.

Who/what is the owner for that existing file? What language is in use?

It's been noted as an issue at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2304 but isn't resolved yet.

Comment: Now there is this https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/2336

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Git and install a downgraded version. 
The version that shows this problem is the 2.23.0. Downgrade it to the 2.22.0 and it works fine without this problem.

Git releases: [All git releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
Git 2.22.0: [Version without this issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.22.0.windows.1)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `config` file from `C:\ProgramData/Git` directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Git 2.24.0.2 and visual studio 2019 - 16.2.3. I couldnt create the path and config file in c:/ProgramData/git/, as I dont have admin rights. It turned out that the windows credentials stored are expired for my user account and when updated using control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Generic credentials for git helped to resolve the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

The "Git" folder was missing from the path c:/ProgramData/Git/Config.  I created the folder (not the config file) and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using Visual Studio GIT extension and open Visual Studio as Administrator if you face below issue

warning: unable to access 'c:\programdata/git/config': permission denied
warning has a dubious owner: '(unknown)
git please transfer ownership to an administrator
github config has a dubious owner

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried some of the tips given above but the problem keep existed. Then I directly went and **updated the visual studios Installer** and the problem fixed.