# In Visual Studio 2019, is there any Macros (the ones with name $()) to call git in the Command Line of the Custom Build Tool?

Tags: git, build, visual-studio-2019

I have a Custom Build Tool and I would like to call `git` from its Command Line.

[image]

I mean `git` included with Visual Studio installation, for example on my computer its path is the following:

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd`

Is there any Macros (the ones with name `$()`) that gives me the right path to `git`?
I would prefer to use a macro instead of hard coding the path.

Comment: If git is in your path could it work from any location?

Comment: @tymtam Yes, that is what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `$(DevEnvDir)`.

But you can follow with a relative path to build what you want. Something likeL

```
"$(DevEnvDir)CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe"
```

(The quotes are needed because this is passed to `cmd.exe` and there is a space in the path.)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately now I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592530/latest-update-brings-github-error-on-pull-push-or-sync but it is a different issue.