# can't commit in git hub visual studio19 "has a dubious owner:"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

in Visual Studio *Git failed with a fatal error.warning: 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' has a dubious owner: '(unknown)'.*

Or in Git Bash
*error: open("simpleGit/.vs/simpleGit/v16/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'simpleGit/.vs/simpleGit/v16/Browse.VC.opendb'
fatal: adding files failed*.
I added config' file to Git folder. Changed all permision to Admin. Still not working :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latest Update brings Github error on pull, push, or sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592530/latest-update-brings-github-error-on-pull-push-or-sync)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592530/latest-update-brings-github-error-on-pull-push-or-sync . This one didn't work for me