# warning: 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' has a dubious owner: 'S-1-5-21-2380165290-1749897186-383349493-670437'

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

```
warning: 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' has a dubious owner: 'S-1-5-21-2380165290-1749897186-XXXXXXXXX-670437'.
For security reasons, it is therefore ignored.
To fix this, please transfer ownership to an admininstrator.
ERROR: Your account is suspended. Please check with your installation administrator.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Git config file values are also fine.

[image]

I have access to a GitHub enterprises repo with a maintainer. It was working before today only I a getting the error. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latest Update brings Github error on pull, push, or sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592530/latest-update-brings-github-error-on-pull-push-or-sync)

Comment: No. I shared the config file also its looks fine but I am getting errors. I hope it is a different issue

Comment: *Git* is not producing this error message. Git is simply getting denied by the OS early on, and hence unable to clone the repository.

Answer (score 7):

The error seems coming from the file owner issues.

Try to change the `C:\\ProgramData\\Git\\config` owner, by right-click it -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced (with similar meaning, I am not using an English version of Windows), then change the owner to, for example, `Administrator`, as the error log indicates.